# Please, can someone explain me what does this assembly code do?

Tags: sorting, assembly, vector, riscv

```
codeA:
.data
N: .word 10
V: .word 90,50,40,20,30,10,80,70,60,100
.text
main:
li t2, 0 //t2 <-0
la t3, N //t3 <- @N
lw t3, 0(t3) //t3<- N
la t4, V //t4 <- V
addi a7, x0, 1 //a7 <- i <- 1
p1:
beq t2, t3, end
lw a0, 0(t4) // a0 <- V[?]
ecall
addi t2, t2, 1
addi t4, t4, 4
j p1
end:
```

I'm new in this and I'm struggling trying to understand what does this code do.

I'm trying to "translate" it to C language or some kind of pseudocode to make it more understandable. I just got stuck in the middle of it.

Comment: Clearly `t2` is counting up to `t3` (which is `N`) and `t4` is iterating the array and the `ecall` (I assume) prints the values ... which part is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

This is doing:

```
int N = 10;
int V [] = { 90, ... };


void main () {

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        printf ( "%d", V[i] );
    }

 }
```

so, printing all the elements of the array from 0 to <N.

However, it is using pointers instead of array indexing.  So, in C, it looks more like this:

```
 int *p = &V;
 for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
     printf ( "%d", *p );
     p++;  // adds 4 to p so it refers to the next int in the array
 }
```

Now, it is not using `printf ( "%d" ... );` but rather MARS/RARS syscall/ecall #1 to print an integer as text to the screen — but this `printf` is the best mapping of that sys/ecall for C programming.